# Page Not Found Component displaying on all pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have just about completed my first real React JS project except for one bug. My `404/Page Not Found` component is displaying on all pages. I have looked all over the internet and through multiple similar questions here on SO, but I am still at a loss of how to fix this problem. Here is the relevant code (with parts irrelevant to the issue removed; I can provide more code if it is necessary):

**Module imports:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

**State/login functions/authorized pages route guards here:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history} >
          <Switch>
            <Route render={(props) => (<HeaderNavbar {...props} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus} role={this.state.role} key="header"/>)}/>
            <Route exact path="/" component={TitlePage} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => (<Login {...props} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} key="login" />)}/>
              {this.state.role === "Student" ? (
                this.studentAuthorizedPages()) :
                null}
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={UserProfile} />
              {this.state.role === "Instructor" ? (
                this.instructorAuthorizedPages()) :
                null}
              {this.state.role === "Administrator" ? (
                this.adminAuthorizedPages()) :
                null}
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
            {/* <Route path='/404' component={PageNotFound} />
            <Redirect to="/404" /> */}
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I *believe* this issue has something to do with `{Switch}`'s direct parent-child requirement, but I'm not sure.

So far I have tried:

1. Adding additional `<Switch></Switch>` around other parts of the code inside `<Switch>`. I tried this to see if it was a parent-child issue; but the bug remained.
2. Removing the line with `HeaderNavbar` in it.
3. Writing the `{PageNotFound}` route as either of the following:

```
Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} 
Route path="" component={PageNotFound}
```

4. Using a Redirect statement (as is commented out in the code above). This prevented the app from displaying the `{PageNotFound}` component on every page, but then the app routed to the `{PageNotFound}` component on initial load, any page refresh or when a user logs out (which makes sense because logging out Routes the user back to the title page; hence basically the same as an initial load).

These are the main approaches I have tried in addition to some other smaller changes which didn't amount to anything.

I am using:

*React 16.13.1
React-Router 5.1.2*

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You messed up with Switch, BrowserRouter and Router:
Change

```
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch  } from "react-router-dom";
```

according to this pattern:

```
<Router> // or BrowserRouter
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/about">
            <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

see [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

If you want to use `history` prop, change `BrowserRouter` to just `Router`. [Docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Router):

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: At one point in development, I had to remove Router from this import statement. As you can see I'm using the {history} prop. I tried your solution and was then given the error "<BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`. It also breaks a lot of my other functionality as I have a few this.props.history.push() statements in various functions. Is there a way I can keep the history prop functionality? I tried to import Router as a separate statement below, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So use Router instead of BrowserRouter, which can use history. See [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Router)

Comment: For some reason, import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"; results in only the HeaderNavbar component rendering...

Comment: This is because `route` without `path` prop [always match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string)